# Neo4j throws java heap exception while creating relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I done bulk upload on Neo4j of two different file, say file "A"(contaning 10000 records) and file "B" (contaning 9000 records).
Now I have third file say file "C" (having 10 million record (rows))

File "C" describes the relation between file "A" and file "B".

When the processing starts for file "C"  it throws Java heap size exception, I have 4 GB of ram and increased heap size up to 3 GB. Althoug if I reduce the size of file "C"  up to 2 million records then it works fine

Iam using Neo4j 1.9 version.

Please suggest why is it so? and how to sole it.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 3):

Are you doing this with Neo4j's normal API, or with the bulk inserter? I'm assuming the normal API, and I'm assuming you're doing everything in one transaction? Either use the bulk inserter, or break up your transactions, as transactions are kept in Memory until flushed to disk on commit, which is most likely causing your Heap errors.